# What happens to work done when there's an infinitesimal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Actually I was in a thermodynamics class (High school). My teacher actually used $$dW=Fdx$$
Then something confused me like this equation $$dW=pdV+Vdp$$
Which I actually derived like $W=pV$ and taking differential and thus getting the above equation.

Similarly it is defined that $W=Fx$ (ignoring dot product for a moment,thus assume 1d case). And taking differential we get $$dW=dFx+Fdx$$
Initially I questioned the existence of $dF$. Then I found that $dF=pd \sigma$ (which I actually learnt in thermodynamics).

But this was so skeptical. I searched the web and I didn't find anything good about infinitesimal force and the work equation that I derived.

Probably this can be wrong. But to make sure I'm asking these questions

Are force infinitesimal? And can they be? And is my work done right one or not?

And what if work is a function of Force and Displacement instead of just displacement? $W(F,x)$

(Sorry if there's any mistake. I was very much confused about this. If there's any mistake please mention that. Thanks!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equation

$$dW=xdF+Fdx$$

The first term on the right will always be zero because it assumes that the displacement is constant and the force varies, yet no work done if there is no displacement. For example, I can vary the force that I apply to a fixed wall but if the wall does not move I do no work.

The situation is a little different in the thermodynamics case of

$$dW=pdV+Vdp$$

Because there are two possible types of work: Boundary work ($pdV$ work) and flow work ($Vdp$ work).

The first term (boundary work) applies to closed systems, i.e., systems where mass does not flow into or out of the system but where the system boundaries are movable. The example often used is a gas in a cylinder fitted with a movable piston. Work is done in expansion or compression of the gas (expansion or contraction of the system boundaries).

The second term (flow work) applies to open systems where work is done to push or pull mass across the system boundaries where a pressure difference exists.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Work is defined as *force times displacement*. Therefore $dW=F dx$. $W=Fx$ holds only in the very special case of a constant force. But in that case $dF=0$.

Comment: And also only in the very special case of the displacement starting at $x=0$, so that $\int_0^x dx^\prime=x$.

Comment: Thanks bro. But I have doubt. What if workdone is a function of force and Displacement instead of being just displacement. Then in that case Force is not just constant, but will be a variable $W(F,x)$ . Then can the equation that I mentioned be valid?

Comment: @Sanjay In general, work depends on both, force and displacement. The differential form $dW=F dx$ captures this general dependency. To get the total work along a path one has to evaluate the integral $\int F dx$.

Answer (score 1):

the work is

$$W=\int F(x)\,dx\quad \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dW}{dx}=F(x)$$

or

$$W=\int x(F)\,dF\quad \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dW}{dF}=x(F)$$

example

$$F=k\,x~\quad\Rightarrow~ x(F)=\frac Fk$$

thus x and F are not independent